# Sending various parameters (JSON) using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

This is the interface method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST (“url/myurl")
Call<JsonArray> sendParameters (@Header("x-imei") String imei, @Header("x-id-cliente") String idCliente, @Field(“param1") JsonObject param1, @Field(“param2") JsonArray param2, @Field(“param3") JsonArray param3, @Field(“param4") JsonArray param4,@Field(“param5") JsonArray param5);
```

And the method to use it:

```
Call<JsonArray> peticion= RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(getActivity()).sendParameters(settings.getString("imei", ""), settings.getString("idCliente", "”),param1,param2,param3,param4,param5);
```

This way, the call is not working.

I tried changing all the interface parameters to String, and doing param1.toString(), param2.toString() and so on in the call, and is not working neither.

Is there a simple way to send JsonObjects and JsonArrays in a POST, using Retrofit 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a custom class which you want to pass as a POST body

```
class CustomClass {
   String param1;
   String parma2;
   String param3;
   //all of your params with getters and setters
}
```

Then you change the Retrofit method according to your new CustomClass instance with the @Body annotation:

```
@POST (“url/myurl")
Call<JsonArray> sendParameters (@Header("x-imei") String imei, @Header("x-id-cliente") String idCliente, @Body CustomClass customClassInstance);
```

And eventually you make the call to post data:

```java
CustomClass customClassInstance = new CustomClass();
customClassInstance.setParam1(...);
//...and so on

Call<JsonArray> peticion= RetrofitClient.getRetrofitClient(getActivity()).sendParameters(settings.getString("imei", ""), settings.getString("idCliente", ""), customClassInstance);
```

**EDIT:** removed the @FormUrlEncoded annotation

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: that is Retrofit 1, I am using Retrofit 2

Comment: I will keep on searching on Monday, im almost out of the office. Thanks for your help.